# Why is video button grayed out in Windows Phone 7 camera chooser task?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

I'm wondering why the video capture button is always grayed out (disabled) when using the both the `Camera Capture Task` and the `Photo Chooser Task` with `ShowCamera = true;`?

[image]

I've tried to find ways to enable it, but without any success.

I'm developing for Windows Phone 7.5.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's greyed out because Camera Capture and Photo Chooser both only support single images, not videos.

If you're looking to capture video, take a look on MSDN here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: @GrahamWagar Right, I have already had a look at that. But that means I have to create an entire UI including logic just to be able to record video.
So essentially this is a left out feature by Microsoft? If so it's a little unintuitive to just diable the video button instead of removing it.

Comment: @Zappel Afraid so - you have to decide what you're doing with the video as you capture it (like stream it to IsolatedStorage) rather than have an entire video just handed back to your application from an inbuilt Task. I see what you mean about the video button, but I think it's to remain consistent with what a user normally sees when launching the camera.

Comment: @GrahamWagar If I understand you correctly, there already exists a built-in task for recording video? I have not been able to find that.

Comment: Sorry @Zappel I obviously lost some clarity in that comment. There is no built-in task and so you have to set up and handle the stream yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can :). Here is the tutorial for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394041(v=vs.105).aspx

And to download complete sample click here 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Video-Recorder-Sample-5e800bbf